# column headings getting truncated

Tags: sql, unix

i am running my query via a unix script. i need column headings. For this i have used set heading on.  my requirement is to pull data from a table concatinate it using a pipe, write it in a text file.  i need column headings along with the data.this file needs to be sent as feed to some other party. my query is something like this

```
select column1||'|'||column2||'|'||column3||'|'||column4......
from table;
```

I have more than 100 columns in my query

in my oputput the column data comes up correct  but the column headings get truncated. i see  dashes i.e '------' instead of column names after three column headings are displayed.

the output is something like

```
column1||'|'||column2||'|'||column3||'|'||col
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20-APR-13|0.990000|0|0|Y|voice|yes|0|0

20-APR-13|0.990000|0|0|Y|voice|yes|0|0
```

( in the above exmaple i tried with 9 columns. i can see data for 9 columns but the headings after 3 column headings the fourth one is truncated and rest are not displayed.)

I couldn't paste my original query with more than hundred columns here.

Can somebody let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: Can you not post your query without the 100+ column headings?

Comment: the query is just selecting all columns and i am using a pipe to append them as this is the way they are expected in the file by teh third party. As i mentioned the data is coming out good but teh heading i.e the column name gets truncated.

Comment: ua correct in my above statement- using a pipe to concatenate them

Comment: I had a similar problem when i was exporting a table to a text file for an email...It was sown to the fact that there wasnt enough space on the page to display it all so it produced a load of line

Comment: Dev N00B...how did you correct it and why it is that teh data in the columns is appearing but the column headings aren't

Comment: My report was being exported to an email so all i had to do was set the width long enough to fit it in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the configuration of the shell to set the column size:

```
 COLUMNS=1024
 stty columns 1024
```